# How the garbage collector free those new object created without any reference name

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a class Response

```
public class Response
{
    public Response(String response,String platform,String url)
    {
        this.response =response;
        this.platform = platform;
        this.url = url;
    }
    ...
}
```

saving this object in table, from DAO

```
{
    Response response = null;
    response = new Response(jsonObject.toString(), platform, url);
    sendgridResponseDAO.save(response);
    ...
}
```

or

```
{
    sendgridResponseDAO.save(new Response(jsonObject.toString(), platform, url));
}
```

Functionally both are the same. Please help me to understand in the second way, how and when the garbage collector frees those new objects?
Will the second way create memory issues and slow down the system?
Which one is efficient?

Comment: If the `response` variable is not used after the call to `save`, those 2 code snippets are identical after compilation. This is also not something that will cause any perfomance issues. This is purely about code readability.

Comment: Objects may get garbage collected when **no** reference to them exist. So why should it help when the reference, at the time when it still existed, had a name? By the time, the object is eligible to garbage collection, there is no relationship between that name and unreachable object. Not that names ever mattered to the garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

What you call a "reference name" is just another reference that points to a given object, in this case it's a local variable.

As soon as the object is unreachable from *any* garbage collection root, it will be garbage collected.

As long as the `save` method is running the `Response` object will be reachable via the argument of that method in *both* cases (whether or not you assigned it to a local variable first) and chances are that the `save` method will store a reference to that object somewhere (so that a later commit can actually save the data), so in this specific case the local variable is unlikely to cause any difference in the garbage collection behaviour.